# Hiding iOS Status Bar's Text

Tags: ios, swift2, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar, nsstatusbar

This question **is not about hiding the status bar**, but merely **hiding the text of the status bar**.

I could nt find it anywhere to approach this problem

UBER app does this, when we open the side menu in uber, the status bar **text** disappear,

Comment: I don't think there is a sanctioned way of doing this (i.e., public APIs). My guess is that Uber is just hiding the bar (using the standard methods), and placing instead a custom view of the same size and color, but without any labels/icons.

Comment: I doubt that @NicolasMiari cause we can see that the text slides up.

Comment: I haven't seen the Uber app, but then they must be "sliding up" that text themselves (with a custom animation). The default status bar has a pretty much limited API: You can choose between two color styles and whether to show it or not (globally, or on a per-view controller basis). That is all.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't hide `text` of `status bar`. you can hide status bar with animation something like,

```
  CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
 //   self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
    self.view.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height);
}];
```

It is in obj c and just for understand concepts, convert in swift!

You can add new view instead of status bar as custom status bar look

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int itemToHide = 0;
[[objc_getClass("SBStatusBarStateAggregator") sharedInstance]                  
beginCoalescentBlock];
[[objc_getClass("SBStatusBarStateAggregator") sharedInstance]
_setItem:itemToHide enabled:NO];
[[objc_getClass("SBStatusBarStateAggregator") sharedInstance]     
endCoalescentBlock];
```

please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189431/how-to-hide-statusbar-icons-in-ios?answertab=votes#tab-top) link. it's may help you.